# UITabBar - updating the alpha value and rendering it? (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, grand-central-dispatch, uitabbar

Upon launching my app, I set am "hiding" the tab bar with:

`UITabBar.appearance().alpha = 0.0`

This is done because some logic is done in order to decide what to display upon launch. It all works, yay! **BUT**  (oh, Stackoverflow time) when the user is all done screwing around with what I have showed them, it is time for the tab bar to reappear. So in a completion block I have (obviously):

`UITabBar.appearance().alpha = 1.0`

Voila! **WAIT NO!** Ok so, `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())`? Any luck? **NO**

Ok fine fine, so let's do a `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()`. That should do it, right? **BONK, NO!**

So what's even stranger? Well, when I open a modal on top of this view (with the tab bar still *displaying* at alpha 0.0 but the code already *instructed* it to be 1.0 at this point) and then close it, when the view reappears, the tab bar gets redrawn (I assume) and appears with the alpha at 1.0 and showing with all its glory.

So, what gives? And how can I allow the bar to show after the initial state has been drawn to the screen and alpha updated?

Help!

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue not too long ago, except in the context of the navigation bar. I was curious as well if there exists some sort of means to have the navigation bar redrawn on command. What I observed is if you slid your finger as to move the new page (even slightly), the correct default would appear. Therefore, I concluded this is an issue with redraw not taking place until some sort of interaction occurs. Unfortunately, it seems as though it isn't possible to have this done programmatically.

However, here's the solution I was able to garner that is related your problem:

[Swift 3]

Rather, than using `navigationItem.titleView?.tintColor = UIColor.white`,

I used:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white, NSFontAttributeName:    UIFont(name: "Copperplate", size: 24.0)]
```

However, I'm not sure what the correlate is with the tab bar for your scenario. Perhaps, you could figure that out. (I post all of this for those who had my issue and to explain where your issue likely lies).

Now, for your situation. I believe that setting alpha to 0 is likely not the greatest way to approach your problem in the first place.

Give this a try:

`UITabBar.appearance().isHidden = true`

Hope my solution works or this leads you in the right direction.